# Can visual studio report which file its compiling now?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Sometimes I have errors which are caused by a particular cascading sequence of #include's... it would be much easier to debug if visual studio could give a kind of running commentary on which file it was currently processing. Can it be persuaded to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already outputs the source code file name in the Output window.  If you also want to see which #include file it is processing then use Project + Properties, C/C++, Advanced, Show Includes = Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually.  Insert:

```
#pragma message(" put name of file here ")
```

at the top of every header file.

Not as good as [nobugz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607205/can-visual-studio-report-which-file-its-compiling-now/2607597#2607597) suggestion, but good to remember as a quick and dirty way of seeing if one or two headers files are being included at all.